# LINQ: Selecting "Deep" in a hierarchical object? Selecting all childs that have the same parent?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Can anyone help?

I currently have a class file called Member that stores an object reference and the object reference of its parent. I then have a LIST which contains "many" members. It really like a flat file system, but it works great with linq as i can see give me ALL childs that has a parent of X. Using the Object reference field of the Parent property.

Now i was thinking of recreating my class file and adding a new field which would hold a LIST of Member and remove the Parent property - this way i only have 1 object but there are other objects with this object. Hope that makes sense? :-)

So if i have this new object, how could i use linq to Get all childs of a specific parent? A direct descendent? and would it be possible to flatten the file i.e return the items as single objects which are part of a LIST.

I would love to hear anyones comments on which method is better, i.e. what i have now and hierarchy approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sample code would be good, otherwise this is all hypothetical

Comment: I agree with @BrokenGlass, if you provide code samples to illustrate your question it'll make your intentions **much** clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you do hierarchical collections, remember that there are multiple different data structures to handle this type of problem. there is one that's rather complex, but provides amazing performance. It basically consists of a Dictionary keyed off integers containing the entire collection. The objects themselves keep a Parent relationship, and have a HashSet children collection that's lazy loaded. This allows you to easily get the collection of parents or children for any object at any level of the tree.

The comments are correct though. Without some samel code, I can't give you an example of how this would look. this is all theoretical.